# Include xml-files in Sonar-Analysis (Android Project)

Tags: android, xml, plugins, code-analysis, sonarqube

I just configured [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to analyse my android project but realized that only the Java-files are analyzed by default.

Is there a (easy) way to include the xml-resources in the analysis?
I could not find a plugin for Sonar in their project page but maybe there's something out there?!

Comment: what should this plugin do? what should be measured?

Comment: At least count lines and files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar offers a XML-Plugin:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin

> Any XML file can be validated with
>   this plugin. The plugin provides
>   static code analysis of XML files
>   within Sonar. Typical use cases are
>   validation of files for coding or
>   usability standards.
>
> The following functionality is
>   provided:
>
> XML validation
>   XML schema validation
>   Configurable rules using XPath
>   sizing (files, lines of code)
>
> The XML
>   validation is available out-of-the
>   box. The configurable XPath rules
>   requires some knowledge of XPath.
>
> The plugin scans the following files
>   by default: .xml, .xhtml. The file
>   extensions and the file inclusion
>   patterns are configurable.
>
> The plugin imports the XML files in
>   Sonar, and performs the validations.
>   The checks are configurable in the
>   Sonar rules repository.

Comment: Wow, a completely new plugin. Thanks!

Comment: but will this xml plugin analyse according to android lint ?? please reply @oers

Comment: @Shruti no idea, sorry. But android lint seems to be disconnected from the sonar server atm, so I don't think that this plugin can be used in the lint standalone version